# How to find mailchimp campaign ID using API

Tags: python, mailchimp

I am trying to get mailchimp campaign ID using `/campaigns/list` endpoint.
Then I need to use the id to invoke `/reports/unsubscribes` endpoint. Here is my code using mailchimp python sdk:

```
m = get_mailchimp_api()
campaigns = m.campaigns.list()
for campaign in campaigns['data']:
    cid = campaign['id']
    title = campaign['title']
    unsubscribes = m.reports.unsubscribes({'cid':cid})
```

This code is throwing `mailchimp.CampaignDoesNotExistError: Invalid Campaign ID: Array` exception.

If `id` field does not have campaign id then which field would have? I have tried all other fields that had `id` in them  but without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`campaign['id']` is the correct id to use, but you need to pass the id directly, not in a dictionary, i.e.:

```
unsubscribes = m.reports.unsubscribes(cid)
```